# HBase as web app backend

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Can anyone advise if it is a good idea to have HBase as primary data source for web-based application? My primary concern is HBase's response time to queries. Is it possible to have sub-second response?

edit: more details about the app itself.

- Amount of data: ~500GB of text data, expect to reach 1TB soon
- Number of concurrent users using the app: up to 50

The app will be used to present reports about data stored in HBase, like how many times keyword "X" occured in last 24h. For ~80% of requests from that app I will know the exact key, 20% will be scans (I'm looking into HBase schema design related topics to make it run fast)

Comment: This depends on the type of your application, the number of users it will have and of course on your data. Please describe a little more in detail what your requirements are.

Comment: @rretzbach I added some description.

Answer (score 3):

You can use HBase as a backend for a webapp (see for example Gap's presentation [here](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/1-serving-apparel-catalog-from-h-base-suraj-varma-gap-inc-finalupdated-last-minute)  or EBay's presentation [here](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/8-h-base-the-use-case-in-e-bay-cassini)).

As you noted yourself the point is to get the right schema and  key design

Answer (score 2):

Yes building a web app on Hbase which responds in real time is not unrealistic. Take a look at Opentsdb which exposes timeseries stored in hbase though a web frontend. Although Opentsdb has optimized the storage schema a little and used caching underneath. But the key to faster access in Hbase application lies on the RowKey design. see http://hbase.apache.org/book/rowkey.design.html