# Can the HBase database system be used as a live application database with CRUD features?

Tags: database, hadoop, hbase

I have been reading more about the low-latency ability that HBase database system offers on Hadoop.  While most Hadoop data stores are meant for write-only  map/reduce functions, HBase appears to have low-latency update/delete features as well.

Is HBase a good candidate to be used to replace existing live application databases?

Answer (score 0):

I do use HBase as a back end for a client facing web application. It all depends on how the data is structured in Hbase for faster retrieval (all ties back to RowKey design) and how updates/CURD operations are handled (adding versions)

additional reference 
[HBase as web app backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111820/hbase-as-web-app-backend)

[hbase as database in web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479115/hbase-as-database-in-web-application)

The answer is YES one can replace an existing database by carefully evaluating the primary objectives of the application (especially performance)

Comment: That's great news.  Our current app runs on SQL Server.  The main searchable data is really read-only.  Configuration stuff is the CRUD.  For transitioning to HBase, we could do a combined config db (SQL Server) and datamart (HBase).  Is this recommended, or just move it all to HBase?

Comment: Yes, you can go with a tandem approach. I will encourage you to do a quick POC with smaller data set and evaluate your app requirements.